# Process key events BEFORE handled in Remote Desktop session

Tags: c#, keyboard, remote-desktop

I have a key listener which processes key presses and act on it. For example, CTRL+ALT+1 execute a certain function in the key listener. When I have a remote desktop session opened, some key events are processed directly by remote desktop.

For my application its crucial that EVERY key event gets processed in order to work, even when the user is in working in a remote desktop session.

Clarification:

PC1:

- runs keyboard hook application
- runs a few applications
- one of the applications is a remote desktop session to PC2

PC2:

- irrelevant what this PC is doing

When I press a key on PC1, I want to be able to act on that, hence, the keyboard hook application. This works fine, until my remote desktop session has focus. In that case, "some" keys are processed by remote desktop directly, without passing the events to my keyboard hook application.

Is there a solution to catch the key events before they are sent to remote desktop?

The key hook application I have so far:

```
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Main()
    {
        keyMapper = new KeyMapper();

        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        // handle key events
    }
```